# Laravel 4 Response::download() from external url source

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I can't seem to find out whether it is possible to create a download link via `Response::download()` method with an **external** URL file source instead of local file path. For example:

```
Response::download('https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.zip','Download.zip');
```

I'm hosting my static and upload file on Amazon S3 and would like to create a download link when the requested users have access to it. All I get from the testing above is a **FileNotFoundException** error popping up stating that file does not exist.

Comment: Hey har2vey - to the best of my knowledge, `Response::download` will only work for files hosted on your filesystem.

Comment: @JamesBinford your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 2):

As @James Binford said in the comments, it is not possible to use `Response::download()` for files on an external source. It may not be perfect, but you can always redirect to the URL

```
Redirect::away('https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/file.zip');
```

Depending on the file type it will open as "normal" download (e.g. zip files) or, if the browser supports it, the contents of the file will be displayed (e.g. images or text files)

Alternatively you can download the file from the server to the application server (e.g. using *curl*) and then use `Response::download()`

Comment: Just a note. This exposes your AWS S3 endpoint to anyone that's looking. Even though the URL is still your application, the download comes directly from S3